# StackExchange.Redis SetAdd(key, val) crashes with key = GUID

Tags: c#, .net, redis, stackexchange.redis

Very annoying crash with `StackExchange.Redis` `SetAdd(key, val)`.

I want to set a set with the programs GUID as a key.

I found (after 3 hours debugging) that `SetAdd(key, val)` works with some GUID, but crashes with others:

```
        string key = "02639d71-0935-35e8-9d1b-9dd1a2a34629";
        const string val = "somevalue";

        db.SetAdd(key, val); // <=== Works

        key = "02639d71-0935-35e8-9d1b-9dd1a2a34627";
        db.SetAdd(key, val); // <=== CRASH @@!!@!@!
```

The difference is the last character "9" vs "7"

Doesn't `SetAdd` work with the local GUID as a Key?

Environment: C# .NET 4 Win 8.1 VS2013

Crash message:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'StackExchange.Redis.RedisServerException' occurred in StackExchange.Redis.dll
Additional information: WRONGTYPE Operation against a key holding the wrong kind of value
```

The crash point in `StackExchange.Redis`

[image]

...

I tested this Code in LINQPad. It crashes on the same place. The first GUID works, the second doesn't.

It seams that the crash is not due to this is the starting app GUID.

More test with different GUIDs. Only that ending with '7' crashes.

```
    key = "02639d71-0935-35e8-9d1b-9dd1a2a34622";
    key = "02639d71-0935-35e8-9d1b-9dd1a2a34623";
    key = "02639d71-0935-35e8-9d1b-9dd1a2a34624";
    key = "02639d71-0935-35e8-9d1b-9dd1a2a34625";
    key = "02639d71-0935-35e8-9d1b-9dd1a2a34626";
    key = "02639d71-0935-35e8-9d1b-9dd1a2a34627"; // <= crashes
    key = "02639d71-0935-35e8-9d1b-9dd1a2a34628";
    key = "02639d71-0935-35e8-9d1b-9dd1a2a34629";
```

...

`KeyExists`,  `StringIncrement`, `StringSet` work well with key = my GUID.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Redis keys are opaque. That message:

> WRONGTYPE Operation against a key holding the wrong kind of value

simply means that you have previously stored data in that key of a type that isn't a "set". Try (in redis-cli):

```
TYPE "02639d71-0935-35e8-9d1b-9dd1a2a34627"
```

which will tell you the data type of the existing data. You can only use `SADD` if either the key does not exist, or if it exists **and is a set**.

Comment: OMG. It crashes because I have stored a string with that key before. Who writes these error messages? Why the message is not "The DB already contains other element with that key. Use different key!".. Thank you very much. +1

Comment: @Miroslav "who writes these error messages?" that error is verbatim from the server, so probably Salvatore Sanfilippo :)

Comment: I know that. :) I'm programming since 1986, but I was misled by this exception (having 3 days experience with Redis). I searched what is wrong with the type of the key from  `StackExchange.Redis` point of view. Poor me :)